# Does Play's template engine work on Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, playframework

I am planning to migrate a Play 1.x application to Grail 2.x. I am trying to reuse the client side code as mush as possible.

I would like to know whether the Groovy based templates used in Play framework's HTML files will work on Groovy on Grails framework's .gsp files?

Comment: Are you asking how to use Play's Templating Engine (.scala.html) in Grails? I imagine English isn't your first language, but your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/templates) regarding the Play framework templates I can say that you won't be able to simply take the same template files from Play and use them in Grails.

While Play may be using Groovy as the engine to parse the templates there are quite a few features (message, actions, etc.) in the template engine that are not based on just Groovy and are based on the Play framework. Thus, these will not be supported by Grails.